# How to loop through all XElement attributes and get their values

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How to loop through all XElement attributes and get their values?

```
foreach (SyndicationElementExtension extension in f.ElementExtensions)
{
    XElement element = extension.GetObject<XElement>();

    // How to loop through all its attributes and get their values?
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple - use the [`Attributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attributes.aspx) method:

```
foreach (var attribute in element.Attributes())
{
    string value = attribute.Value;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539428/how-to-get-all-possible-image-urls-from-rss-feed-item)

```
var img2 = feeds.Items
     .SelectMany(i => i.ElementExtensions
                       .Select(e => e.GetObject<XElement>().Attribute("url").Value)
                )
     .ToArray();
```